# rand() only the last 20 rows in the table

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have 1000 lines in my table `posts`.

I'd like to ignore the 980 lines, rand() only the latest 20 ones and show only 4 results to the user (this 4 rows are always in the latest 20 rows).

id is auto increment, so I'd like to get the last 20 id.

```
select id, name, photo, text from posts order by rand() limit 4
```

This will rand all the 1000 lines and gets 4 results. I'd like to rand only the latest 20 `ids` and show the results, eg:

```
993 - josh - img.jpg - some text
987 - marie - img2.jpg - some text
982 - ben - img3.jpg - some text
995 - alfred - img4.jpg - some text
```

notice that I rand only the id 980 till 1000.
Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Just use a nested `SELECT`, first selecting the last 20 posts (using `ORDER BY id DESC`), and then randomly selecting 4 of them:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, name, photo, text
      FROM posts 
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 20) p
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 4
```